# Angularjs two way binding between directive and controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I got list of countries, which will be populated in a dropdown box. I made it as a directive with list items.

And it on click of the country, the country name should be updated in $scope.selected which is defined in the controller.

Unfortunately i couldnt pass the data from the directive to the controller if the list item is clicked. 
How should i map it so that on click it updates the name and code.

[Here is the JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/abarfhr8/)

Thanks

** Pasting the directive code **

```
myApp.directive("dropSelect",function(){

    return{
            restrict:'E',
            scope : {
                items : '=items',
                selected:'=ngModel'
            },
            template:'<input type="text" ng-model="selected.name" placeholder="country">'+'<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="selectedCountry(item)">{{item.name}}<li></ul>',
           link : function(){

           },
            controller:function($scope){
            $scope.selectedCountry = function (item){
                console.log(item);
                $scope.selected.name = item.name
            }

            }        
    }

})
```

**Edit 1:**

adding @ symbol doesnt throw error but adding = symbol throws error

```
selected:'=ngModel' //throws error
selected:'@ngModel' //no error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is your `selected` object in your directive. The exception it throws leads towards that away.

In the html you bind with `selected.name` which means `selected` in your directive will be bound with the `name` property of `selected` in your controller.

However when you select an item your trying to set a `name` property of the `selected` object in your directive which obviously it doesn't have as its just a string.

So the solution:

```
       $scope.selectedCountry = function (item){
            console.log(item);
            $scope.selected = item.name
        }
```

Just set the name to `selected` in your directive.

http://jsfiddle.net/abarfhr8/1/

---

EDIT:

However i would restructure it slightly. First initialize your selected object,
so `$scope.selected = $scope.items[0]` in your controller. Then change the `ng-model` to `ng-model="selected"` so that your returning the whole selected object.

finally in your directive do:

```
        $scope.selectedCountry = function (item){
            console.log(item);
            $scope.selected = item
        }
```

Now when you run and select an item the code and name inputs populate correctly.

See second fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abarfhr8/2/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.You saved my day.

Comment: What is the use of = and  & and @ here

Comment: No problem, the `@, =, =?, &` tells angular how to bind between the directive and outside world. You can either have two way binding, optional two way binding, one way where the property is an accessor method to get the value and more. This should hopefully explain it. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope- Also you can have `=` on its own. It will expect the html attribute to have the same name as the scope property.